# Apache Windows MOD_REWRITE &

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

One of our clients is using Apache 2.2 as a reverse proxy server (Yes, stupid of them) and we're seeing some very funky behavior when trying to redirect some URLs and I'm curious if anyone has seen anything like this/has a solution. Google doesn't offer much assistance on this one.

We're doing two with formats similar to this: redirects (I had to remove the https: so I can post this - I'm not posting links):
//domain.com/text

to:
//domain.com/folder/page.request.do?page=page.eFileloginPage&efiletype=0

What we're getting as a result is:
//domain.com/folder/page.request.do?page=page.eFileloginPage/efilefiletype=0

Here is the redirect:
RedirectMatch ^/text                                                              https://domain.com/folder/page.request.do?page=page.eFileloginPage&efiletype=0

Apache is redirecting &efiletype=0 to /efileefiletype=0.

Anybody know why Apache is doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had to add a \ in front of the & in the redirect:
RedirectMatch ^/text                                                 https://domain.com/folder/page.request.do?page=page.eFileloginPage\&efiletype=0

I can't seem to find any documentation in Apache that shows this has to be done, but it resolved the problem.